# Why doesn't our report data update automatically? How can we make it update the data every time it is run?

Tags: crystal-reports

We have a really simple Crystal Report that is just pulling info about jobs from our Viewpoint database. The only parameters are Company, Department and Status, each of which have default values that do not change.

When the report is run, it should update with new jobs that have been entered, new amounts, etc. Instead, all data remains the same and jobs that have been entered since the last time the report was run does not show up.

Here is our code:

```
SELECT 
  "JCJMPM"."Job",
  "JCJMPM"."Description",
  "JCCM"."ContractAmt",
  "JCCM"."JCCo",
  "JCCM"."Department",
  "JCCM"."ContractStatus",
  "JCMP"."Name",
  "ARCM"."Name"
 FROM   
  (("Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCJMPM" "JCJMPM" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCCM" "JCCM" ON ("JCJMPM"."JCCo"="JCCM"."JCCo") AND ("JCJMPM"."Contract"="JCCM"."Contract")) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCMP" "JCMP" ON ("JCJMPM"."JCCo"="JCMP"."JCCo") AND ("JCJMPM"."ProjectMgr"="JCMP"."ProjectMgr")) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Viewpoint"."dbo"."ARCM" "ARCM" ON ("JCCM"."CustGroup"="ARCM"."CustGroup") AND ("JCCM"."Customer"="ARCM"."Customer")
WHERE  
  "JCCM"."JCCo"=1 
  AND "JCCM"."Department"='50' 
  AND "JCCM"."ContractStatus"=1
ORDER BY
  "JCCM"."JCCo", 
  "JCCM"."Department", 
  "JCCM"."ContractStatus"
```

Comment: How are you running the report (via the Report Viewer, CR itself, an application, etc.)? Is your report set to "Save Results"? Have you tried running this query directly on the database to see if the missing results are in there?

Comment: Ryan, I have run it in CR itself as well as through Viewpoint (software). The "Save Data With Report" option was checked under Report Options (in CR), but even after I unchecked it the results do not appear. I have verified the missing results are in the database.

Comment: And the missing records don't appear even when the report is refreshed?

Comment: Correct. And I have refreshed in CR and in Viewpoint, as well as verified the database in CR.

Comment: That SQL query is the _exact_ query used in the CR, but it returns different results if it is run directly on the database...? That can't be right. Either your results are still cached in the report or some of the records are being suppressed via formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a left join : LEFT OUTER JOIN "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCCM" "JCCM"
and Where clause : WHERE
  "JCCM"."JCCo"=1 
  AND "JCCM"."Department"='50' 
  AND "JCCM"."ContractStatus"=1

The where clause will kill the left join and will turn it to an inner join, Change the SQL to this one and try again:

```
SELECT 
  "JCJMPM"."Job",
  "JCJMPM"."Description",
  "JCCM"."ContractAmt",
  "JCCM"."JCCo",
  "JCCM"."Department",
  "JCCM"."ContractStatus",
  "JCMP"."Name",
  "ARCM"."Name"
 FROM   
  (("Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCJMPM" "JCJMPM" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCCM" "JCCM" ON ("JCJMPM"."JCCo"="JCCM"."JCCo") AND ("JCJMPM"."Contract"="JCCM"."Contract")
AND   "JCCM"."JCCo"=1 
  AND "JCCM"."Department"='50' 
  AND "JCCM"."ContractStatus"=1
) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCMP" "JCMP" ON ("JCJMPM"."JCCo"="JCMP"."JCCo") AND ("JCJMPM"."ProjectMgr"="JCMP"."ProjectMgr")) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Viewpoint"."dbo"."ARCM" "ARCM" ON ("JCCM"."CustGroup"="ARCM"."CustGroup") AND ("JCCM"."Customer"="ARCM"."Customer")
ORDER BY
  "JCCM"."JCCo", 
  "JCCM"."Department", 
  "JCCM"."ContractStatus"
```